# In Apple Mail, How can I delete a message without moving to the next one, causing the next one to be marked as read?

Tags: mail.app, email

I typically leave messages as unread if I need to remember to read them later.

Also I like to keep my inbox clean, so I delete mail I don't care about saving.

When I select a message and press delete, the selection jumps to the next item in the list. Many times, this is the item I just marked as unread for later.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (albeit slightly lengthy) way to do this is to create a custom service, like so:

Create a new Automator Service. Have it take no input in Mail and put the following code into a "Run JavaScript" action:

```
mail = Application('Mail')
mail.includeStandardAdditions = true
for (i in mail.selection()) {
    mail.selection()[i].delete()
}
```

Save the service. Then go to System Preferences > Keyboard, select Shortcuts at the top, and select Services in the sidebar. Scroll to the bottom to where it says "General" and you should see your Service there. Assign it a keyboard shortcut. This shortcut (so long as it does not conflict with any existing shortcuts) will allow you to delete a selected Mail message without selecting the next conversation.

Comment: This deselecting method is a feature I was unaware of, cool to learn new things. However this is just as annoying because there are just as many steps involved, and you must use the keyboard AND mouse.

Comment: See the update I made. Would this be preferable?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

The easy way is to use the "List view".

As long you use the preview window it will mark email as read as soon it shows in the preview window.

The more complicated is to move the cursor upward then delete, now it wont mark the unread as read because it will move to next read (assuming it is above the just deleted). Try it, and take not which way did you move /up or down.